# table view with 3 buttons

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a code for a table view with a cell that i created. Each cell holds three buttons. Each button should have an image as a background image.

This is my code for the CellForRowArIndex:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellView" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = nibLoadedCell;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        //----- select the correct button from the cell
        button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:(i)];


        //----- cleaning the button, drawing it's corners, borders and giving it an action
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        button.clipsToBounds = YES;


        //------ Setting up the btnImg in order to place on the buttons (if is for checking i'm not taking pictures out of the array bounds)
        UIImage *btnImg = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        if (((indexPath.row * 3) + i - 1) < photosArray.count) {
            btnImg = [photosArray objectAtIndex:((indexPath.row * 3) + i - 1)];

            //NSLog(@"I am at indexpath.row: %d",indexPath.row);
            //NSLog(@"I show image number %d in the array",[photosArray indexOfObject:btnImg]);
            NSLog(@"Expression is: %d",((indexPath.row * 3) + i - 1));
        }


        //------ Add btnImg to the button
        [button setBackgroundImage:btnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];



        //------ Giving special tags for each button in order to recognize it later
        button.tag = imageButtonTag;
        imageButtonTag--;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

As you can see, the for loop in my code is in charge of taking the images from my "photosArray" and placing them in the correct button in the cell.

**The issue:**
The first ~23 buttons get the correct images. Afterwards, (requires to scroll down a bit) starting image 24, the images start repeating. Image 24 is equal to image 0. Image 25 equals image 1 and so on…

I checked many things already. Everything looks fine! I even checked the photosArray indexOfObject and the numbers are correct.

You might think the array is made this way. I thought so too, but i assure you it's fine. I deleted my for loop and instead entered the following code:

```
//----- select the correct button from the cell

button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:(1)];
 //----- cleaning the button, drawing it's corners, borders and giving it an action
[button setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.layer.borderWidth = 2;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
button.clipsToBounds = YES;

//------ Setting up the btnImg in order to place on the buttons
UIImage *btnImg = [photosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//------ Add btnImg to the button
[button setBackgroundImage:btnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This gives me a tableView with one button in each cell and the buttons get the right images…

One last thing I tried, is this code in my previous code right after creating btnImg:

```
if ([btnImg isEqual:[photosArray objectAtIndex:0]]) {
    NSLog(@"Match found at: %d",[photosArray indexOfObject:btnImg]);
}
```

But nothing matches (although when i run it i see the images are the same).

This issue is driving me insane for about a week now and i would really appreciate it if someone could help me solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what is going on, but one thing which you can try is not to use a reusable cell to make sure that your problem is not else where. Just do "UITableViewCell *cell = nil" and then let each cell be a new one. Atleast you will be able to know for sure that it is not the reusable cells which are causing the problem

Comment: And also, where are you getting imageButtonTag from. Looks like you are setting button.tag at the end and then in the beginning trying to get a button with a tag. Did you set the tag in the nib. Then do not overwrite it in code.

Comment: I set the tag in the nib of the cell. I've got buttons 1 2 and 3. But i need to change it afterwards cause when i click a button i need to have the possibility to loose it, so i want to know which button was pressed. I know there are a couple of ways to do it. But this is the one i chose. You think it bothers that i set it again in code?

Comment: Yeah, because when you use reusable cells, the same cell will come back again and then the buttons are with some other tag values and your call of [cell viewWithTag...] does not return any thing, so it is failing there. For start, just do not reset the tag and see. What you can do is, subclass the button and have another variable to keep unique identifier for each button if that is the way you want to go

Comment: infact, that is the reason your other code works, because you are not setting the tag again.

Comment: Man!!! You solved it! I can't believe it… You should get an award or something! Amazing...

Comment: All i had to do is comment out the two lines that are reseting the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting of view tag is causing it not to be identified. Better way for you to identify each control is through subclassing or some other strategy, especially since you are using tags to get to the control